# C# mainform showing when subform closes

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to close my 2nd form and show my 1st form, without creating a new object.

```
frmMain Mainfrm = new Mainfrm();
Mainfrm.Show();
this.Close();
```

On my main form there is special coding for certain users of the program, and by creating a new object is tosses everything away that is mainly created when the mainfrm is first created on application launch.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think we can with such description. Can you be more clear about what you are trying to achieve and what do you have so far? What does "without crating a new object" mean? What does "tosses everything away" mean?

Comment: Do you close your `Mainfrm` when your second form opens?  If not, shouldn't it still be up and available when your second from closes?

Comment: No i do not close my main form i just hide it

Comment: If you get your answer chose it or be more specific to answer you

Comment: That is 100% the correct answer thanks, but my reputation is to weak to vote for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the main form

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // to open form2
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

in the form2

```
private mainForm mainForm; //mainForm is the name of the Main form
    public Form2(mainForm mainForm) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// to close form2 and show main
    {
        this.mainForm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't close your main form, hide it instead. Do `this.Hide();` so it will not be visible to the user and your main form data will remain. You can call `this.Show()` to show it again without creating a new instance.

Comment: if the main form is hidden how will i call the this.Show() method to show the mainform again?

Comment: @Wynand: I assumed that the main form is `this`, so you can call it any time. `youMainForm.Hide()` will hide the form from user. `yourMainForm.Show()` will display it again to the user. Note that calling `Hide()` will not close or dispose the application instead just hide it.

Comment: @Wynand van Heerden :just idea you can send the instance of the main in the constructor of the form2 like a window and show it when you close form2

Comment: Akrem would you be able to give me a sample code of how to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered showing the 2nd form as a dialog?

From the main form:

```
new Form2().ShowDialog();
```

This causes the main form to remain open, but the user is unable to access it until it closes then 2nd form.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instantiate another Windows Form in the same way. Make it modal or modeless and you should be fine. You won't lose the information from your other form.

See here for the [MSDN article on Dialog Boxe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chz8edb.aspx)s.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the main form to hide while the second is open? Or just make sure it is still there.

In the normal course of events, a form created in another form create a type of parent child relationship, so you should automatically see the first form when the second closes. Having the data reflected in the first form requires getting the data back, which can be done via setting up event handlers.

The exception is if you close the main form, which can be avoided by hiding it instead and then unhiding it when #2 is finished.

Comment: Yes i just want to hide it while the second form is open

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, it probably put `Application.Run (new Form1())` in your `static void Main()`.  That causes the application to exit when Form1 closes (so that's why Form2 doesn't stick around.)

Instead you can use `Application.Run()` (without parameters) and call `Application.Exit` explicitly when you want to end the program.